# Using generic method in an interface to return a List of variable type based on input from a file

Tags: c#, generics, interface, factory

I have an application that needs to read data records from files and create lists of objects based on the type of record it is reading. There are six possible types of records that could be read in. I discovered the FileHelpers library to facilitate creating objects of whatever type I specify. I'm trying to write this in such a way that one reader/file parser class can handle returning any type of record read in. I am exploring the possibility of using a generic interface/method to do this, but am kind of stuck on how to correctly implement it.

I have a ReaderFactory that will give me a specific type of Reader back, and all Readers inherit from MainReader.

```
public interface MainReader<T> 
{
    void ReadFile(string vsFileName);
    List<T> GetRecords();
}


public class ReaderFactory<T>
{
    MainReader<T> GetReader(RecordType recordType)
    {
        MainReader<T> oReader = null;
        switch (recordType)
        {
            case RecordType.TypeA:
                oReader = new TypeAReader();
                break;
            case RecordType.TypeB:
                oReader = new TypeBReader();
                break;
        }
    return oReader;
}
```

The readers themselves will take a file and, using the FileHelpers library, read the data into a list of objects.

```
class TypeAReader : MainReader<RecordTypeA>
{
    public List<RecordTypeA> oRecordList = new List<RecordTypeA>();

    public void ReadFile(string fileName) 
    {
        FileHelperEngine<RecordTypeA> oEngine = new FileHelperEngine<RecordTypeA>();
        RecordTypeA[] records = oEngine.ReadFile(fileName);

        foreach(RecordTypeA record in records)
        {
            oRecordList.Add(record);
        }
    }

    public List<RecordTypeA> GetRecords() 
    {
        return oRecordList;
    }
}
```

When building, I get the error "cannot implicitly convert type TypeAReader to MainReader". If I change the factory to return a new TypeAReader or TypeAReader, I get the same error that I can't convert TypeAReader to MainReader.

I believe there is a way to do this, I must just be missing something. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: cast it to required type e.g. `oReader =(MainReader<T>)new TypeAReader()`

Comment: What's your driver for creating this class - instead of just using the already generic `FileHelperEngine{T}`?

Comment: if you'll provide more context e.g. how a consumer of your factory provides RecordType values and how you consume list of records, a better design can be suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you compilation issue - you missing a cast: `oReader =(MainReader<T>)new TypeAReader()` will do a job. If you want to understand why it doesn't get compiled consider next call:

```
new ReaderFactory<int>().GetReader(RecodrTypeA)
```

Obviously `TypeAReader` doesn't implement `MainReader<int>` interface.

Regarding a design of your factory, compiler actually hints you that where is no relation between `RecordType` enum and `T`. So first of all you can omit  RecordType descriptor:

```
public class ReaderFactory
{
    MainReader<T> GetReader<T>() 
    {
        var returnType = typeof(T);
        if(returnType==typeof(RecordTypeB))
            return (MainReader<T>)new TypeBReader();
        if (returnType == typeof(RecordTypeA))
            return (MainReader<T>)new TypeAReader();
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

you can also add some static type protection your factory by limiting T to an interface to prevent `GetReader<int>()` calls (still arguable)

```
interface IRecordType{}
class RecordTypeA:IRecordType{}
class RecordTypeB:IRecordType{}
...
MainReader<T> GetReader<T>() where T:IRecordType
```